# Error Handling in Laravel, how can specify on Routes?

Tags: php, error-handling, routes, laravel, laravel-4

The basic of this is, I want to handle errors from my API and make sure all errors thrown via the API give json responses but for the website I want HTML responses to be sent.

If there a better way then purely applying the logic from http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information and using something like:

```
if (Request::is('admin/*'))
{
    //
}
```

This works but seems a tiny bit clunky doing it for each exception type that might be thrown? The documentation doesn't seem to have anything but I was wandering if there's anything that might work so can apply errors for set route wildcards? Something like:

```
App::error('admin/*', function(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an App::error filter and in that filter do the Route check, and then send a response in json. A simple example like this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception) {
    if (Request::is('api/*')) {
        $message = get_class($exception) . ":: message: " . $exception->getMessage();       
        return Response::json(["success"=>false,"message"=>$message]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Route Group http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups and apply a filter on the group, or prehaps you could use the App::error method if you declared it inside a prefixed route group http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing . I'm not 100% whether either method would work, but if you have no luck the Laravel IRC is very active see http://laravel.io/irc for a quick easy web client.

Comment: Got an example of how one applies filters to define custom error handlers for route groups?